# How to access a private property of a property in child struct const method?

Tags: c++

I created a class named `Course` with private property `std::string code` and another class named `Student` with private property `std::string id`. Then I created a class named `Enrollment` as:

```
class Enrollment {
  private:
    Course course;
    Student student;

  public:
    struct EnrHash {
      size_t operator() (const Enrollment &__e) const {
        auto _code = std::hash<std::string>() (__e.course.code);
        auto _id = std::hash<std::string>() (__e.student.id);
        return (_code ^ _id);
      }
    }
}
```

I can't access the `course` and `student` properties even after changing them to *protected*. I have tried replacing it with `course.getId()` but still not working.

I want to understand why that is and how to deal with it.

Thanks :)

Comment: Either make course and student friends of Enrollment or make their fields public.

Comment: private is private for a reason. Create a (protected) getter function in the base class to gain access. By `const Student& GetStudent() const noexcept { return student; }` a getter allows you to limit access to readonly, something that changing student to protected or public cannot do

Answer (score 0):

Make `struct EnrHash` a [`friend`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) of `Enrollment`:

```
class Enrollment {
  protected:
    Course course;
    Student student;

  public:
    friend struct EnrHash;
    struct EnrHash {
…
    };
}
```

Comment: It won't be enough because `code` and `id` are also `private` :) It seems op needs to add getter functions instead of cascading friendships (which would be a nonsense).

Comment: It is a solution, but it breaks encapsulation (and I think good design). Course and Student as members is not a good design here : An Enrollment is a relation between the two, so it should be references to a Course and a Student (or non-owning pointers).